# Document Db Request Continuation Token Not set on the 1st iteration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-.net

I have a document db collection that contains about 1500 docs. My eventual goal is to build an api with the above as my persistence layer. I read the docs (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-paging-support-with-top-and-more-query-improvements/) that mentions to use *request continuation token* via feed options for paging.

Have the following method  on a console app to understand the same: The problem or the issue here is that the first time the query is executed the continuation token=null but the second time the query is executed the continuation token = "some value"

*So my question is shouldn't the continuation token be set the first time itself? or am I missing something obvious*

```
    //field
    private static readonly FeedOptions DefaultOptions = new FeedOptions {     EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,MaxItemCount = 1};
    //method
 private static async Task<bool> QueryItemDocuments(string collectionLink)
    {

        IDocumentQuery<Item> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Item>(collectionLink, new SqlQuerySpec()
        {
            QueryText = "SELECT * FROM items",
        },DefaultOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

        var loopNumber = 0;
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            loopNumber++;
            var results=(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Item>()).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0}",results.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Loopnumber :{0} Token {1}", loopNumber, DefaultOptions.RequestContinuation ?? "Null");

            Console.WriteLine("Id: {0},Name: {1}", results[0].Id, results[0].Name);
        }
        return query.HasMoreResults;
    }

sample results from console :
       Count 1
       Loopnumber :1 Token Null //why is this null?
       Id: 1dbaf1d0-0125-11e0-88a8-005056957023,Name:Energy Drink
       Count 1
       Loopnumber :2 Token -       RID:jq4gAIZqMwACBBBBBBB==#RT:1#TRC:1#PKRID:0
       Id: 244a8230-0231-11e0-8c8b-005056957023,Name: Gluten Free Dish
```

**Edits**: Ideally, I would send back the continuation token on the response headers allowing the client to fetch more if needed (on my web api) - so my method would like

```
     public Get(int? page=1,int? size=20)
```

so when I send the response back with the first 20 I need to send back the continuation token for the client to request more: so if the continuation token is not set the first time - meaning when I retrieve the 1st batch of 20, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so i figured that it might be a bug in the SDK or by design - do not know, however when I query for the result using `Document Db's rest end points` - the `continuation token`  is indeed set on the first batch's response. Here is the sample code that used:

```
   private static async Task QueryItemDocumentsUsingRestApi()
    {
       //About rest end points to query documents here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt670897.aspx
        IEnumerable<string> continuationTokens = null;
        var continToken = string.Empty;
        var verb = "POST";
        var resourceType = "docs";
        var resourceLink = string.Format("dbs/{0}/colls/{1}/docs", DatabaseName, CollectionName);
        var resourceId = string.Format("dbs/{0}/colls/{1}", DatabaseName, CollectionName)
        var authHeader = GenerateAuthSignature(verb, resourceId, resourceType, authorizationKey, "master", "1.0"); // look here for how this is generated https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/rest-from-.net/Program.cs

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", _utcDate);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-08-06");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("authorization");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", authHeader);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-documentdb-isquery", "True");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-max-item-count", "5");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-continuation", string.Empty);
            var qry = new RestSqlQuery { query = "SELECT * FROM items" };
            var result = client.PostWithNoCharSetAsync(new Uri(new Uri(endpointUrl), resourceLink), qry).Result;
            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var pagedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagedList>(content);

            if (result.Headers.TryGetValues("x-ms-continuation", out continuationTokens))
            {
                continToken = continuationTokens.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, the behavior of the REST API and the node.js client (which is just a thin wrapper over the REST API) is that you get the continuation token in a header for the REST API and in a third parameter in your callback function. I have never tried to access it directly from .NET code. Only node.js.

Comment: The problem is that with the client was that the `continuation token` was `not set` until it executed the `loop twice` thus failing it to set on retrieval of 1st batch itself, whereas `with REST api` the `continuation token` is `set` with the `retrieval of the 1st batch itself`.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Two thoughts:

1. You don't need to manually process the continuation token when using `HasMoreResults` and `ExecuteNext`. `HasMoreResults` checks if there is a continuation token and when you call `ExecuteNext`, it's automatically added.
2. I suspect that the reason you don't see a continuation on the first round is that it's the outgoing `DefaultOptions` and it's not updated until it goes out again on the second `ExecuteNext`. I'm thinking that your output on the second loop is actually the first continuation token.

Comment: Thank you for your input - As I mentioned in my post , my eventual goal is to build a web api around this, so I would not be using  HasMoreResults as shown here, I would send back the continuation token on the response headers allowing the client to fetch more if needed - so my method would like ` public Get(int?pageNo:0,int size:20) ` so when I send the response back with the first 20 I need to send back the continuation token for the client to request more: so this doesnt help if it is not set the first time.